# How do I scrape multiple websites with BS4 and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've recently started making small programs in Python. I made a Webscraper using BS4 but I am not able to use this scraper for multiple websites.

The Webscraper is made to check the availability of an RTX 3070 Videocard for various Dutch retailers. However, I can only make this work for one website. I know that website A uses different classes for their availability in contrast to website B. So, I figured I needed to create an IF... Else statement in combination with a For...Loop

Note: This scraper is **not** meant to 'scalp' the products.

The following works like a charm... for a single website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import smtplib

response = requests.get('https://www.alternate.nl/Grafische-kaarten/RTX-3070')


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

posts = soup.find_all(class_='listRow')

with open('RTX_avail.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    headers = ['Title', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Availability', 'URL']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)


    for post in posts:
        title = post.find(class_='name').get_text()
        link = post.find('a')['href']
        improved_link = 'alternate.nl'+link
        price = post.find(class_='price right right10').get_text().replace("€ ","").replace(',-*','')
        inStock = post.find(class_='stockStatusContainer complete').get_text()
        availability = 'Not Available' if "Pre-order" in inStock else 'Available'
        brand = title.split(' ', 1)[0]
        print([title, brand, price, availability, improved_link])
        csv_writer.writerow([title, brand, price, availability, improved_link])
```

Using the following does **not** work:

```
urls = ['https://www.alternate.nl/Grafische-kaarten/RTX-3070', 'https://www.coolblue.nl/videokaarten/nvidia-chipset/nvidia-rtx-3070']


response = requests.get(urls)
```

I also tried to re-create the scraper but to no avail:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = ['https://www.alternate.nl/Grafische-kaarten/RTX-3070', 'https://www.coolblue.nl/videokaarten/nvidia-chipset/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3000-serie/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3070']

data = []

def letCrawl (url, data):

    for pg in url:
        if url == 'https://www.alternate.nl/Grafische-kaarten/RTX-3070':
            page = requests.get(pg)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
            ticker = soup.find("h1").text
            data.append(ticker)
            break
        else:
            page = requests.get(pg)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
            soup.find("h1").text
            data.append(ticker)

print(data)
```

Is there anyone that can help me out? I just need to able to let it run on multiple websites. I think I can figure the if...else statements myself but feel free to give me some suggestions.